# Font Family/Display Issue in Safari 12 on macOS Mojave

Tags: safari, font, mojave

I just upgraded to macOS Mojave a few days ago and I have noticed an issue with the fonts displayed in Safari for sites/themes that I have created on Tumblr.

It appears that Safari reverted back to the default of Times New Roman and I'm not sure why; this is only an issue in Safari. The fonts are correct when viewing the site(s) in FF and Chrome. It is also only happening on desktop; the view on my iPhone and iPad are showing the correct font.

EX: http://romanoffsbite.tumblr.com

The font I used on this site is Calibri and it was displaying correctly until I upgraded to Mojave; now, it's loading in Times New Roman and I cannot figure out why or how to fix it.

I have searched for this issue the last day or so and all I have been able to find is the solution to the fonts showing as thin and blurry in Mojave, but there hasn't been anything, that I could find, that applied to incorrect font(s) displaying.

(the solution for the thin and blurry fonts did work)

SPECIFICS

- OS: macOS Mojave 10.14
- Safari: 12.0
- Font Not Displaying: Calibri (normal, bold, italic)
- Website Example: http://romanoffsbite.tumblr.com

Again, any help with this would be amazing! I'm not sure where else to go from here, so I have come to all of you smart folks :)

Thank You!
Nicole

Comment: I can't comment on why Safari does not display Calibri (same behavior on my Mac with Calibri installed) **BUT** if you specify more than one font-family in your CSS (at least "sans-serif" but best to specify at least a couple more...) then it won't change fon't families when the browser can't/won't display the one font you specify.

Comment: Have you seen this thread? https://discussions.apple.com/thread/8567339?page=2

Answer (score 2):

Easy fix:

- Open Safari Preferences
- Go to tab "Websites"
- Under General on the left side click "Content Blockers"
- Then turn OFF content blocker for the website you are browsing.

This fixed the issue for me.

Answer (score 0):

Try to restore the fonts in Font Book -> File -> Restore Standard Fonts…